# How to retrieve values from angular material forms with QuerySelector

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-5

I am try to retrieve values from an angular from by using the javascript document.querySelector.
I am able to retrieve input field values but when I comes to radio button, toggles and select box, I am not able to retrieve values.
 I am not able retrieve the value using

```
(document.querySelector('.recurring_subscription') as HTMLInputElement).value
(document.querySelector('.given_to') as HTMLInputElement).value
(document.querySelector('.billing_state') as HTMLInputElement).value



<mat-slide-toggle class="mat-toggle-nusa" class="recurring_subscription" formControlName="recurring_subscription">
  Automatic donate this amount once every Month
              </mat-slide-toggle>
 <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let dt of nusa_given" class="given_to" [value]='dt.value' > {{dt.name}} </mat-radio-button>
```

```
<mat-select formControlName="billing_state" class="billing_state" placeholder="Enter State (required)">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of getNameOfStates | async" [value]="state.abbreviation">
                          {{ state.abbreviation }}
                        </mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using document.querySelector to get the value of your input elements. You can do a 2-way bind to a variable to each one of them using ngModel and access the variable directly.

Anyway, for slide toggle, you have two class attributes:

```
class="mat-toggle-nusa" class="recurring_subscription"
```

Try this instead:

```
class="mat-toggle-nusa recurring_subscription"
```

For radio button, there are multiple elements of the same class. You are using `given_to` in an ngFor. Each element in that loop will have that same class name.

The class `billing_state` does not have a value attribute that you are trying to access.

Also, you should know that radio buttons should be wrapped in a `<mat-radio-group>` which holds the value of the radio group. That is how you know what radio button is selected. 
Example: https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples